# LINQ to SQL classes Data Base in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, data-connections

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnb6p.png)I have been created a data base by LINQ to sql classes .. 
the problem is when  I make connection it in any project , the associations ( or the relations) between tables  don't appear !! 
could the problem be in the data base  it self?

Comment: Do you have foreign keys that relate the tables?

Comment: Draw your ERD!!!!!

Comment: I added a pic to the data base